# How do I create a week to date Tableau calculation with a Monday week start

Tags: tableau-api

I'm working on a project where I must display several weeks of Sales, week to day.  So, if today was Wednesday, all weeks displayed would show Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday.  Weeks start on Monday and go to Sunday.  I changed the week start in my data source settings but that did not fix my issue.

My original formula is as follows:

`IF Datepart('weekday', [Date])<=DATEPART('weekday', TODAY()) THEN [Revenue] END`
This formula is close to what I need, but it unfortunately includes Sunday.  I think this is because datepart numbers are fixed.

How can I modify this formula to show the days of the week based on a Monday start?

This formula works, but only shows me a single week (user should be able to select the last x number to weeks).
`IF DATEDIFF('week',
DATETRUNC('week'[Date],'monday'),DATETRUNC('week',TODAY(),'monday'))=0
THEN [Sales] END`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just tell it ignore Sunday (day 1). (Edit based on comments - if today is day 1 then show all). Modifying your calc:

```
IF DATEPART('weekday', TODAY()) = 1 THEN [Revenue] ELSEIF Datepart('weekday', [Date])>1 AND Datepart('weekday', [Date])<=DATEPART('weekday', TODAY()) THEN [Revenue] END
```

Comment: You can also set the date properties on the data source via the Data menu to have the week start on whatever day of the week you like. That doesn't affect the calculation but does affect the sort order for presentation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I think the formula above puts me on the right track. I just need help building in the case when the Today equals Sunday. I would then expect to see all values since my week ends on Sunday. I think without this logic, Sunday isn’t showing up.